# Adding a field of an object to list in C# when list

Tags: c#, list, object

So I have a list of objects (AllCompanies), and all the objects in the list inherit from the same class (Company). And I also have a field in the class they all inherit from which is another class entirely (Employees). I want to create a list of every Employee currently active, and I have every company in a list of objects. As you can see below I have tried to simply add the Employee's field to the list, but I get an error because I am trying to convert an object to a list of employees.

```
public class Main()
{
    List<List<Employee>> AllEmployees = new List<List<Employee>>();

    List<object> AllCompanies = new List<object>() { new SmallCompany(), new LargeCompany(), new SmallCompany() };

    AllCompanies.ForEach(delegate(object o)
    {
        // - Here's the problem.
        AllEmployees.Add(o.GetType().GetField("Employees").GetValue(o));
        // - Here's the problem.
    });
}

class Employee
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public Employee(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}

class Company
{
    public List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();
}

class SmallCompany : Company
{
    public SmallCompany(){}
}

class LargeCompany : Company
{
    public LargeCompany(){}
}
```

How can I do this most efficiently?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are doing, but should you define: List<List<Employee>> AllEmployees as List<Employee> AllEmployees instead?

Comment: Why not make AllCompanies a `List<Company>`?

Comment: don't use an `object`.  You're throwing away your types.  Also, `Company` seems more suited for an interface here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't type the list as a list of `object` types.  The objects are all `Company` objects, and the list should reflect that.

```
List<Company> AllCompanies = new List<Company>() 
{
        new SmallCompany(), 
        new LargeCompany(), 
        new SmallCompany() 
};
```

That will remove the need for any of that awful reflection code that will just make life hard.

Once you have that projecting each item into a new item given a selector is easy enough to do:

```
var allEmployees = AllCompanies.Select(company => company.Employees);
```

Comment: Better as `SelectMany` perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG Depends on what he wants to do with it.  In the question he specifically indicated he was looking for a list of lists of employees, not just a list of employees.

Comment: Ah yes, I just saw that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understood what you actually want, but if i did this would be, in my opinion, more understandable and easier solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ICompany> AllCompanies  = new List<ICompany>();
        AllCompanies.Add(new Company());
        AllCompanies.Add(new SmallCompany());
        AllCompanies.Add(new LargeCompany());
        List<Employee> AllEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        foreach(var Company in AllCompanies)
        { 
            Company.Employees.ForEach((Employee)=>
            {
                if(Employee.IsActive)
                    AllEmployees.Add(Employee);
            });
        }
    }
}

class Employee
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public bool IsActive;
    public Employee(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}

interface ICompany
{
    List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
class Company: ICompany
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
class SmallCompany : ICompany
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
class LargeCompany : ICompany
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```